# Truffle ganache debug not working

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, ganache

I have installed truffle and ganache and the @ganache/console.log library.

Furthermore, I have the following contract from an online course which serves as an example to demostrate the debug mode of truffle:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.21;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

import "@ganache/console.log/console.sol";


contract Spacebear is ERC721, Ownable {

    uint256 private _nextTokenId;

    constructor(address initialOwner) 
        ERC721("Spacebear", "SBR")
        Ownable(initialOwner)
    {}

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "https://ethereum-blockchain-developer.com/2022-06-nft-truffle-hardhat-foundry/nftdata/";
    }

    function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }

    function buyToken() public payable {
        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        console.log("got here", tokenId, msg.value);
        require(msg.value == tokenId * 0.1 ether, "Not enough funds sent");

        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        pure
        override(ERC721)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(_baseURI(),"_",tokenId+1,".json"));
    }
}
```

Now, when migrating the contract onto the ganache network and buying a token through `buyToken()` like so:

```
const spacebearInstance = await Spacebear.deployed();
await spacebearInstance.buyToken({value: web3.utils.toWei("0.1","ether"), gas: 300000});
```

the transaction purposefully will fail.

If I try to enter the debug mode of the transaction with `debug txid`, the truffle debugger starts up but the cursor in the terminal jumps out straight of the input line like so:

[image: 1]

If I type any shortcut command it just says for example`Uncaught ReferenceError: v is not defined`

Any idea why this happens?